# Inserting values in a table depending on spatial relation between objects in to tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql, update, st-intersects

I have a new and empty column in a table and I want to insert values, using postgis depending on the spatial relation between the geometries in two tables.

I have one table (points) with benches and another table with cadastres. I now want to add a 1 (one) in the benches table where objects in the benches table intersects cadastres that public owned and a 0 (zero) where they intersect cadastres owned by anybody else.

The cadastres table is `EPSG`: 25832
The benches layer is `EPSG`: 4326

I have tried the following:

```
SET public =CASE WHEN ST_Intersects(a.the_geom,b.the_geom) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END
FROM schema.object_bench a
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM schema.cadastres  WHERE owner = 'public') b
ON ST_intersects(ST_TRANSFORM(a.the_geom,25832),b.the_geom);
```

When I run the query there is no syntax error message but no rows are updated, which not should be the case since all the objects in the benches in table intersects objects in the cadastres table.

Is it the `ST_Transform` operation that fails or is the query in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FROM` list items in an `UPDATE` are in fact *cross joined* to the updated table, and mentioning the same table in that list is effectively a self-join.

In your query example, for each row in `object_bench` (the *updated* table) that is traversed in the `UPDATE`, PostgreSQL creates a result set of a `JOIN` between `object_bench` (*not* the updated table, but the full self-joined table, again) and `cadastre`, and makes those rows available to the `UPDATE`; this, however, is unconditional without a filter reference to the updated table, and there is no link between the result set and the updated row.

Additionally, your `CASE` condition will be *falsey* in 99.99% of cases because the CRS do not match; you'd have to use `ST_Transform` again!

---

An `UPDATE` could look like this:

```
UPDATE object_bench AS b
   SET "public" = (c.owner = 'public')::INT
FROM   cadastres AS c
WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(b.geom), 25832), c.geom))
;
```

Here

- the `cadastre` table is joined to the updated `object_bench` table with a per-row reference in `ST_Intersects` (`b.geom`); this may lead to ambiguous results *if* the `JOIN` returns more than one row (intersects more than one `cadastres.geom`), and if that can be the case, additional decision making is needed
- `(c.owner = 'public')::INT` casts `BOOL` as `INT` based on the matched row attribute; this is just a short syntax for your `CASE` statement

---

Note that `public` is a reserved key word in PostgreSQL (schema `public`) and should better be avoided as column name; use sth. like `"isPublic"` instead.